# Two recruiters two jobs one company

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I have two interviews set up for different jobs within the same recruiting company with two different recruiters, let's call them A and B. The job for A is more interesting, but I would not mind accepting the B job. I'm meeting with both recruiters. Will the fact that I'm seeing two recruiters (but different jobs) be a problem for them? And if so, what's the smart way to resolve it - do I need to pick one recruiter over the other?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem here, so there's nothing to resolve.

I can't imagine that it would be a problem for the recruiters, and I would hope the recruiting company has a way of tracking candidates that are assigned to recruiters, so they have internal transparency. But that's their job not yours.

It's very common to work with multiple recruiters during job searches, and recruiters know this -- their goal is to win you over by making their job offering the most attractive of all your other opportunities.

Comment: I agree.  Now if they were both for the _same_ role, then you have a problem :)

Comment: @JaneS, that's easy you could do both interviews at the same time